# How to tell if a ctree is just a root node?

Tags: r, party

Say I fit a model like this:

```
ctree(Age ~ Kyphosis, data = kyphosis, mincriterion = 1)
```

How could I get the number of splits? How could I get whether it were just a root node?

EDIT:

Packages used:

```
library(caret)
library(party)
library(partykit)
library(plyr)
library(xtable)
```

Error when I try to use `tree.size` as listed in answer below:

```
> tree.size(ctree(Age ~ Kyphosis, data = kyphosis, mincriterion = 1)@tree)
Error in tree.size(ctree(Age ~ Kyphosis, data = kyphosis, mincriterion = 1)@tree) : 
  trying to get slot "tree" from an object (class "constparty") that is not an S4 object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the party package documentation, the `tree` slot in the fitted model is a recursive representation of the tree. You could build your own recursive function to determine the tree size:

```
tree.size <- function(tree) {
  if (is.null(tree)) {
    return(0)
  } else {
    return(1 + tree.size(tree$left) + tree.size(tree$right))
  }
}
```

We can test the function with a tree containing just a root node and with a tree with multiple nodes:

```
library(rpart)  # for kyphosis
library(party)  # for ctree
mod1 <- ctree(Age ~ Kyphosis, data = kyphosis)
tree.size(mod1@tree)
# [1] 1
mod2 <- ctree(Petal.Width~., data=iris)
tree.size(mod2@tree)
# [1] 11
```

**Update:** Based on the updated question, it seems the OP is actually using the `partykit:::ctree` function instead of the `party:::ctree` function. It turns out this is a good deal easier to obtain the tree size, as the returned model is a list of the nodes, so all that is required is the `length` function.

```
library(partykit)
mod1 <- partykit:::ctree(Age ~ Kyphosis, data = kyphosis)
length(mod1)
# [1] 1
mod2 <- partykit:::ctree(Petal.Width~., data=iris)
length(mod2)
# [1] 11
```

Comment: This is an awesome solution! I'm getting an error though. Reads: `Error in tree.size(tree_full@tree) : 
  trying to get slot "tree" from an object (class "constparty") that is not an S4 object `
>

Comment: @goldisfine are you using the `ctree` object from the `party` package? Unfortunately you didn't include enough code in your question for me to reproduce what you're doing (you would need to show all the packages you've included).

Comment: I've added the packages and the error to the question.

Comment: @goldisfine I've updated my answer based on your new information. It turns out you were using the `ctree` function from the partykit package instead of the party package. This highlights why it's important to post questions that include reproducible examples, complete with the package include statements.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with the other answers/discussions to this question, I just wanted to add a little more detail/context in case other users come across the same or similar problems.

While many aspects of the `ctree()` function in the old `party` and new `partykit` package remained the same in order to make transitions easy, almost all of the R and C code was rewritten and streamlined and the internal representation is completely new. The old `ctree()` returned an S4 object that was not flexible enough for everything that we wanted to do with it. The new `ctree()` function returns an object of class `"constparty"` (for recursive partition with constant fit in each node) inheriting from the general `"party"` class.

The number of nodes can be queried with the `length()` method, the number of terminal nodes with the `width()` method. The number of nodes is also reported in the `print()` method. Finally, the node IDs can be queried via `nodeids()`. For a tree with just a root node:

```
data("kyphosis", package = "rpart")
library("partykit")

ct1 <- ctree(Age ~ ., data = kyphosis)
length(ct1)

[1] 1

width(ct1)

[1] 1
```

For a larger tree:

```
(ct2 <- ctree(Number ~ ., data = kyphosis))

Model formula:
Number ~ Kyphosis + Age + Start

Fitted party:
[1] root
|   [2] Start <= 15: 4.475 (n = 59, err = 152.7)
|   [3] Start > 15: 2.909 (n = 22, err = 17.8)

Number of inner nodes:    1
Number of terminal nodes: 2

length(ct2)

[1] 3

width(ct2)

[1] 2

nodeids(ct2)

[1] 1 2 3

nodeids(ct2, terminal = TRUE)

[1] 2 3
```

The package vignettes also provide many additional useful details. `vignette("partykit", package = "partykit")` has a general introduction to the package and its classes; `vignette("constparty", package = "partykit")` describes the class for trees with constant fits; and `vignette("ctree", package = "partykit")` provides additional details on `ctree()`.